# Objective-C selector with invalid characters?

Tags: swift, objective-c, selector

When interfacing with the Objective-C runtime, it seems that selector names are allowed to have "illegal" characters. One can use this kind of selector to add new methods and call them in ways that would not be possible in code.

Let me give an example:

```swift
final class Test: NSObject {
    @objc func test() {
        print("This is Sparta!")
    }
}

// Xcode indeed shows a warning "String literal is not a valid Objective-C selector"
let selector = Selector("invalid? !@#$%^&*()")

// let's add a new method, having the same implementation as an existing one
let testMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(Test.self, #selector(Test.test))!
let added = class_addMethod(Test.self, selector, method_getImplementation(testMethod), "v@:")
print("class_addMethod result: \(added)")

// let's see if calling the method works
Test().perform(selector)
```

The above code creates a selector with an invalid(?) name, uses the selector to add a new method to the test class, and calls that method afterward. Of course, one cannot directly call that method via the dot notation, as they would get a compiler error, however, the newly added method can be called via `performSelector`.

And to my surprise, the above code generates the following output:

```
class_addMethod result: true
This is Sparta!
```

This means that we can define, at runtime, methods with names that would generate compile errors if written in the class declaration.

I couldn't find any documentation supporting this behavior, intuitively since selector names are bare strings, dynamic method lookup should work with any kind of string.

Is this expected behavior? If yes, are there any limitations (except maybe length) on the contents of a selector name?

Comment: Since selectors are method signature/names, all characters aren't allowed to declare a function/method. I'd tend to says that's why, and the limit being the method naming.

Comment: @Larme the method signature is not part of the selector

Comment: See [NSSelectorFromString(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/1395294-nsselectorfromstring)

Comment: @Willeke unless I missed something, the documentation for NSSelectorFromString only talks about passing the UTF-8 representation to `sel_registerName`, and alsomentions about the colon. There are no other details about what characters are allowed in the selector name.

Comment: The documentation for `NSSelectorFromString` talks about "A string of any length, with any characters", "cannot be converted to UTF-8" and "only due to insufficient memory".

Comment: Wow, don’t know I missed that part. This is what I was looking for, can you add an answer, @Willeke?

Comment: That's internal implementation detail but in practice the only forbidden character in obj-c runtime is the C-style null terminator character.

Comment: @Kamil.S I don't think it's forbidden, just that it will make the selector shorter than expected :)

Answer (score 1):

In Objetive-C's grammar `@selector` names are `Identifiers`

> Identifiers
> An Objective-C identifier is a name used to identify a variable, function, or any other user-defined item. An identifier starts with a letter A to Z or a to z or an underscore _ followed by zero or more letters, underscores, and digits (0 to 9).
>
> Objective-C does not allow punctuation characters such as @, $, and % within identifiers. Objective-C is a case-sensitive programming language. Thus, Manpower and manpower are two different identifiers in Objective-C. Here are some examples of acceptable identifiers:

```
myname50   _temp   j     a23b9      retVal
```

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/objective_c/objective_c_basic_syntax.htm

> Is this expected behavior? If yes, are there any limitations (except maybe length) on the contents of a selector name?

I think it is expected behavior; the Obj-c runtime keeps a hash table of selectors and anything that can be encoded in an NSString and hashed should work, it follows that the check for valid Identifiers is made at compile time not runtime. I would not rely on this behavior.